# Duplicate Logger output in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, logging

I'm using pry-rails on one of my Rails projects but the console output is being duplicated everytime I use the Rails logger.

Example:

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 21550
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.6)
[1] pry(main)> Rails.logger.info "Hello! Is there echo in here?"
Hello! Is there echo in here?
I, [2016-07-03T17:21:02.430621 #21550]  INFO -- : Hello! Is there echo in here?
=> true
```

So, I am getting a puts-like output and the the formal output.

I'm sending my Gemfile, but as a summary:

- I'm using rails_12factor but its on production only and I checked and I am in the development environment.
- I've tried almost every configuration found elsewhere
- This is the only project that is showing this kind of trouble, but I can't find the great difference with the rest of them.

Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.2.3'

gem 'bundler', '>= 1.12'
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.6'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'pg'
gem 'pg_search'
gem 'activerecord-postgis-adapter'
gem 'eu_central_bank'
gem 'money-rails'
gem 'rack-cors', :require => 'rack/cors'
gem 'puma'
gem "refile", require: "refile/rails"
gem "refile-mini_magick"
gem "refile-s3"
gem "rest-client"
gem 'redis'
gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra'
gem 'devise'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'postmark-rails'
gem 'memcachier'
gem 'dalli'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'aasm'
gem 'pry-rails' #, groups: [:test, :development]
group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
group :development do
  gem 'quiet_assets'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'dotenv-rails'
  gem "better_errors"
  gem "binding_of_caller"
end
group :test, :development do
  gem 'awesome_print'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem "capybara"
  gem "selenium-webdriver"
end
gem 'angular-rails-templates'
gem 'jader'
```

Comment: This is usually caused by initializing 2 loggers in some configuration file or environment file. If you post a project on github that reproduces the issue, it would be easy to help you further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938124/why-is-my-rails-server-logging-everything-twice), and what you did:

Start pry and type:

```
 config.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
```

That seems to work.

Comment: In what folder should I find that file?

Under lib I've only got assets and tasks.

Comment: I did the exact opposite.
Starting pry I made Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT) and I've got a single output. Maybe you should clean your previous answer and update the latter?

Comment: I'm glad it is fixed.Can you accept the answer please? unless there is something else you can add.